# z3 PROOF=true option namespaces & quantified variables

Tags: z3

I'm using the `TRACE=true` and `PROOF=true`options to generate logs.

Without the `PROOF=true` option identifiers that are never declared are used for quantified variables in pattern terms for quantifier-triggers. For example for a quantifier `∀x. {f(x)} f(x) = x` I would get a log similar to:

```
[mk-app] #3 f #2
[mk-app] #4 pattern #3
[mk-app] #5 = #3 #2
[mk-quant] #6 quantifier_name #4 #5
```

where there is no `[mk-app]` line for `#2` in the log. Is this understanding of how the logs work correct?

With the `PROOF=true` option enabled the identifier that should represent the quantified variable is used for proof steps. For the same quantifier as above I might get a log like:

```
[mk-app] #1 true
[mk-app] #2 asserted #1
[mk-app] #3 f #2
[mk-app] #4 pattern #3
[mk-app] #5 = #3 #2
[mk-quant] #6 quantifier_name #4 #5
```

My first guess was that the identifiers for proof steps and regular terms should be in separate namespaces such that `#2` would still be undefined in the "terms namespace" in the log above.

This interpretation does however not solve another kind of issue that I'm seeing with the `PROOF=true` option enabled where I'm getting log similar to the following for the same quantifier as before:

```
[mk-app] #1 some_term
[mk-app] #2 iff #1 #1
[mk-app] #3 refl #2
[mk-app] #4 f #2
[mk-app] #5 pattern #4
[mk-app] #6 = #4 #2
[mk-quant] #7 quantifier_name #5 #6
```

i.e. the quantified variable is `#2` which is a regular term.

How does one figure out which term is supposed to be a quantified variable in such logs? I've uploaded an [smt file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pQLsJud_fdFN36hNO1v54Ue-wqruapAA/view?usp=sharing) and the corresponding [log file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1a-VtjKGIc2VaNW1WAl3bX7V2BiFqoUp1/view?usp=sharing) I generated with z3 version 4.6.1 (64-bit). The first issue I described happens for the quantifier on l. 50 of the log file with the quantified variable being `#40` (l. 32) and the second issue happens for the quantifier on l. 63 of the log file and the quantified variable `#58` (l. 52).